# Listview runs out of room to display string

Tags: java, android, listview

My app is retrieving a long string from firebase and displaying it in a listview and it runs out of room. There is "..." at the end, which is shown in the picture i attached.[Heres a picture of what the listview shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNBzA.png)

Here is my code. What do i do to make the text wrap/continue to the next line?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Events extends AppCompatActivity {  ListView listview2;
DatabaseReference dref;
ListView listview3;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);
    listview3=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view3);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    listview3.setAdapter(adapter);
    dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events");
    dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `simple_dropdown_item_1line` you have only 1 line of text. Replace it with `simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following properties inside your layout:

```
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="false"
```